# How to install FFI support for PHP via apt on Debian

Tags: php, debian, ffi, apt

How to install FFI support on Debian via apt?

I am currently using php7.4 from deb.sury.org, but it seems there is no FFI support by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ffi` support is now one of the PHP 7.4 extension, just enable/config it.